# PHP/SQL can't insert

Tags: php, sql, insert

So I'm doing a register page for teams. So the user who creates a team will be inserted into a database table called alcs_teams. That's not the problem. Then I'd like to insert them into another table called alcs_member_teams. That keeps track of the members on each team.

So I do an insert query into the alcs_teams which works fine. Then I try to select the team id from the data that was just inserted a few lines below. Does this work? I can't get it to work, it just puts 0 in that field in the database.

```
$member = mysql_query("Select * from members where id=$_SESSION[tid]");
$member = mysql_fetch_array($member);


mysql_query("INSERT into alcs_team (teamid, name, leader, email) VALUES('', $_POST[name]', '$member[name]','$member[email]')");


$teamid = ("Select * from alcs_team where leader=$member[name]");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($teamid);

mysql_query("INSERT into alcs_member_teams (id, alcs_teamid, alcs_memberid, member_name) VALUES ('', '".$row[teamid]."' , '".$member[id]."', '".$member[name]."')");
```

Comment: You're using mysql_fetch_array on an SQL statement - you'll need to run that first, before you can get anything useful from it. If `teamid` is a primary key, then this will probably be easier: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming none of your queries can never fail. Both are bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using parametrized queries whenever possible

Example:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$params = array($name, $email);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO CustomerTable (Name, Email) VALUES (?, ?)';

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);
```

This prevents [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), which can cause a lot of trouble on your site.

Comment: Not only is this not an answer to the original question, you've posted code for SQL Server when the OP is using MySQL.